# How to combine 4000+ commits in github

Tags: github

I realized I have 4000+ messy commits in github. I tried this commands:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~1
```

as I got from the internet, however I would always get this messages

```
Cannot 'squash' without a previous commit
```

Comment: Do you have uncommited files in your repository?

Comment: No i do not have...

Comment: Is this your first push to remote?

Comment: Is your current branch the one with the 4000+ commits?

Comment: yes the current branch has 4000+ commits and I want to create a new branch from it but merge all the commit into one